# Get Date in Java given Week number, week day and year

Tags: java, jodatime

Given Week of the year, the week day and the year, how can we get the Date in Java?

With Jodatime, I tried the following:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
dt.withYear(year);
dt.withWeekOfWeekyear(weekOfYear);
dt.withDayOfWeek(weekDay);
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyMMdd");
System.out.println(dateTimeFormatter.print(dt));
```

But it gets the current Date!

Comment: Doesn't JodaTime return a new (changed) `DateTime` object using `with` instead of changing the underlying one?

Comment: @Neet Yup, all joda-time objects are immutable.

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JodaTime returns a changed copy, so do:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime()
    .withWeekyear(year)
    .withWeekOfWeekyear(weekOfYear)
    .withDayOfWeek(weekDay);
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyMMdd");
System.out.println(dateTimeFormatter.print(dt));
```

And this should work as expected.

Comment: that will produce wrong dates, this small adaption will make it work like it should: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28980155/1245622 @Neet

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer has bug.`.withYear(year)` should be `withWeekyear(year)`. @Neet please update it.

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.WeekFields;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        int weekNumber = 34;
        int year = 2021;
        
        System.out.println(getLocalDate(weekNumber, DayOfWeek.TUESDAY, year, Locale.UK));
        System.out.println(getLocalDate(weekNumber, DayOfWeek.TUESDAY, year, Locale.US));
        
        System.out.println(getLocalDate(weekNumber, DayOfWeek.SUNDAY, year, Locale.UK));
        System.out.println(getLocalDate(weekNumber, DayOfWeek.SUNDAY, year, Locale.US));        
    }

    static LocalDate getLocalDate(int weekNumber, DayOfWeek dow, int year, Locale locale) {
        return LocalDate.of(year, 2, 1)
                .with(dow)
                .with(WeekFields.of(locale).weekOfWeekBasedYear(), weekNumber);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-08-24
2021-08-17
2021-08-29
2021-08-15
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/OYPdoI)

Note that the ***first day of the week*** is `Locale`-dependent e.g. it is Monday in the UK while Sunday in the US. As per the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standards, it is Monday. For comparison, check the [US calendar](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=2021&country=1&wno=1) and the [UK calendar](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=2021&country=9&wno=1). Accordingly, the date will vary as shown in the example above.

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236520/discussion-between-ole-v-v-and-arvind-kumar-avinash).

Comment: Thanks, @OleV.V. for the valuable feedback. My solution agreed with [this website](https://savvytime.com/week-number/united-states/2021). However, your solution agrees with [this website](https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/?year=2021&country=1&wno=1) and [this website](https://www.calendar.best/week-number-2021.html#week-numbers-2021-us) and also with `java.time` API. I have updated my answer to use your solution.

Comment: The different websites reporting conflicting week numbers for USA make me curious.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not using this code correctly, but using 2021 and week number 1 gives me 2020-12-27 (expecting 2020-12-29). I found several other cases where this code doesn't match the week number display in the calendar. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You need to reassign the date afterwards!
the dt.with*() methods simply make a copy of the date.

try

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
dt = dt.withYear(year);
dt = dt.withWeekOfWeekyear(weekOfYear);
dt = dt.withDayOfWeek(weekDay);
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyMMdd");
System.out.println(dateTimeFormatter.print(dt));
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use this native java code using Calendar class:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd yyyy");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 23);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 3);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,2013);
    System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Comment: I bet the OP has a reason for using JodaTime (as anybody has that _really_ needs to work with dates in Java).

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). Likewise, the Joda-Time project also advises migration to the java.time classes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example of how to do it without JodaTime:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Snippet {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String year = "2013";
        String week_of_year = "46";
        String day_of_week = "4";
        String yearweekday = year + week_of_year + day_of_week;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyywwu");
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = sdf.parse(yearweekday);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
YearWeek.of( 2017 , 1 )
        .atDay( DayOfWeek.TUESDAY ) 
        .format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuMMdd" ) )
```

## “Week” ambiguous

The word 'week' is ambiguous. Do you mean week number 1 contains January 1? Or week number 1 contains the first of a particular day of year such as Sunday or Monday?

Or do you mean a standard [ISO 8601 week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date)? To quote from [`YearWeek` doc](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html):

> ISO-8601 defines the week as always starting with Monday. The first week is the week which contains the first Thursday of the calendar year. As such, the week-based-year used in this class does not align with the calendar year.

## java.time

The modern approach uses the java.time classes.

- The troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.
- The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

## ThreeTen-Extra

The [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/index.html) project extends java.time with additional functionality. This includes a handy [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class, just what we need for this Question.

Specify your week-based year number and your week number.

```
YearWeek yw = YearWeek.of( 2017 , 1 ) ;
```

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

You can ask the `YearWeek` object to determine the date of a day contained within its week. Specify a `DayOfWeek` enum object. Note that a [`DayOfWeek`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html?is-external=true) is an object rather than a mere integer or string, providing for [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety) and valid values.

```
LocalDate ld = yw.atDay( DayOfWeek.TUESDAY ) ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).